# I can not upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04 from 11.10

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade

Trying the upgrade results in the following message:

```
"Could not download the release notes-Please check your internet connection"
```

My Internet is working fine. Having just downloaded various updates. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. If you open a terminal window (hold Ctrl+Alt+t) and type the following

do-release-upgrade

it will ask you for your password and it should automatically run the update

Comment: While helpful (and correct), this does not address error with download of release notes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this vid. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaX9qiQMbhg

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.